# Anyone know what type of plant this is? Is the long bare stem common?

Tags: identification

I acquired this plant but don’t know what type it is and therefore best care. Is the long bare stem common, or could it be fuller?

Would also appreciate any tips in caring for it, though I will definitely read up on it once I know its name. Trying to figure out the best location for it, watering requirements, etc. and would like to separate the new pups that are growing in. [image]

Answer (score 1):

According to the [PictureThis](https://www.picturethisai.com/) app, that is **Heartleaf Philodendron**.

Growing tips include:

- The suggested minimum temperature is 15 °C (59 °F).
- Keep soil moist but not soggy.
- Pinch / prune: For a *fuller* plant, pinch beyond a leaf stem; this causes the branch to start a new stem.
- If you want a plant with *longer* vines, don't prune.
- They will climb if you give them a structure to 'grab'.

There are more growing tips on the Philodendron article on the [Guide to Houseplants](https://www.guide-to-houseplants.com/heartleaf-philodendron.html) website.